# Make concat_lines_of( ) work for rawstring

Tags: abap

I am converting some code. In the past string was used, now rawstring should get used.

This worked with string, but now fails with rawstring:

```
data my_table TYPE TABLE OF rawstring.
concat_lines_of( table = my_table sep = `, `)
```

How to make above lines work? In my case rawstring contains utf8 encoded data. The result should be a xstring (sequence of bytes)

It does not really matter here, but in Python this would look like this:

```
my_list = [my_byte_sequence1, my_byte_sequence2, my_byte_sequence3]
big_byte_sequence = b', '.join(my_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

The classic request is to just concatenate a table of bytes into a string of bytes, in that way adding a comma to identify the original lines is non-sense because it's impossible to store a comma as a character (alternative: encode it in a given code page).

If the question is just the classic request, then there's no equivalence of [`CONCAT_LINES_OF`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconcatenation_functions.htm) for the `XSTRING` type.

One workaround is to use [`REDUCE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_reduce.htm) :

```
DATA my_table TYPE TABLE OF xstring.

my_table = VALUE #( ( CONV #( '01FF' ) ) ( CONV #( 'BEEF' ) ) ).

DATA(my_xstring) = REDUCE #(
      INIT aux TYPE xstring
      FOR <x> IN my_table
      NEXT aux = COND #( WHEN aux IS INITIAL THEN <x> ELSE aux && <x> ) ).

ASSERT my_xstring = '01FFBEEF'.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `, ` between the lines is missing. How to get it between the lines?

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the comma in your question. The classic request is to just concatenate a table of bytes into a string of bytes, thus the comma is non-sense. If your question is to concatenate a table of bytes into a string of characters with the bytes represented in hexadecimal, and comma between, then my answer is incorrect. Let me correct it and post another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given you have these inputs:

- a table of byte strings containing characters encoded in a given code page
- the name of the given code page
- the separator character used to separate each line in the output

You want this output:

- a string of bytes containing all lines joined and separated by the separator in the given code page

This can be achieved using this code:

```
TYPES ty_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF xstring WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA: my_table   TYPE ty_table,
      my_xstring TYPE xstring.

my_table = VALUE #( ( CONV #( '01FF' ) ) ( CONV #( 'BEEF' ) ) ).
PERFORM proc USING my_table `, ` 'UTF-8' CHANGING my_xstring.
ASSERT my_xstring = '01FF2C20BEEF'.


FORM proc 
      USING
        itab       TYPE ty_table 
        sep        TYPE csequence 
        codepage   TYPE string
      CHANGING
        my_xstring TYPE xstring.

  DATA(xsep) = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( source = sep codepage = codepage ).

  my_xstring = REDUCE #(
      INIT aux TYPE xstring
      FOR <x> IN my_table
      NEXT aux = COND #( WHEN aux IS INITIAL THEN <x> ELSE |{ aux }{ xsep }{ <x> }| ) ).

ENDFORM.
```

Comment: In my case rawstring contains utf8 encoded data. I don't want a conversion from binary to readable ascii. The result should be a xstring (sequence of bytes).

Comment: OK. Answer adjusted to fit your question.